# Задержка перед очередной итерацией цикла

Tags: javascript, while, three.js

Необходимо сделать задержку между вызовами `spawnEnemy`

```
function spawnEnemy() {
        var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100, 200, 100, 3)
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x00ff00, flatShading: true});
        var enemy = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        enemy.position.set( getRandomInt(-100 ,-4000), 75, 0 );
        scene.add(enemy);
    }

    while (0 < 10) {
        spawnEnemy();
        // delay
    }
```

Comment: про `async/await` слышали?

Comment: Будет ли какое-то описание проблемы? )

Comment: ну вообще очевидно, что человек хочет `delay` между итерациями цикла

Comment: можно setTimeout рекурсивно вызвать 10 раз по условию

Comment: let index = 0;
const st = setInterval(
    () => {
        spawnEnemy(); index++ > 10 && clearInterval(st)
}, 1000);